# "It was a present" or "it is a present" in context?

Tags: grammar, past-simple, present-simple

Do I have to say it is a present or it was a present when a person owns something and they want to say that they were given the thing as a present. For example:

> Person A: When did you buy the tablet?
>
> Person B: I didn't. It **is**/**was** a present.

Is it even a natural response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'It was a present', because the discussion is about the past transfer of ownership. 'It is a present' is something a giver could say, at the time of giving, maybe to remove doubt over whether payment is required, or whether it is to be returned later.